# bash script with asynchronous while loop

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I have the following bash script.

```
your_token=tokenAddress
number_to_airdrop=1
echo "Starting transfering"
while IFS= read -r line
do 
    spl-token transfer $your_token $number_to_airdrop $line --allow-unfunded-recipient --fund-recipient
done < whitelist.txt
```

`whitelist.txt` contains 1000 addresses, so the problem is that when it loops, until the first one is finished(spl-token takes time), the next one doesn't start which causes the whole operation to take really long time.

How can I make this somehow asynchronous in a way that loop starts, though, each token transfer doesn't wait for the previous one before it starts ?

Comment: Run it in the background?

Comment: placing `&` at the end of the command line will place the `spl-token` call in the background and allow the loop to continue; one problem you'll quickly run into, especially if the `spl-token` call is resource (cpu, memory, disk, neetwork) intensive is that your system will quickly slow to a crawl what with the loop trying to push 1000 of these calls into the background (ie, 1000 separate processes trying to run concurrently); there are a few ways to limit the number of concurrent background jobs ... `parallel`, `xargs`, some coding with `wait -n`, some coding around `$(jobs | wc -l)`, etc

Answer (score 1):

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    the-command --and all --arguments &
done < whitelist.txt
wait
```

You can send the command into the background with ampersand `&` and then use `wait` to stop script from going forward until all commands started in the while loop has completed.

Another option is to use [parallel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel)

Comment: Note that this method may be over-parallel -- it'll just start all 1000 transfers at once, which may cause memory etc contention. Using `parallel` will allow you to control how many run at the same time.